# Problems with video playback

Tags: gstreamer

I have h264 video track and aac audio track inside mp4 container and I want to play it, but when I run my pipeline there's just first frame shown and no sound.

Here's my pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/home/dmitry/Downloads/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux \
    demux.audio_00 ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink \
    demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queues might not be large enough for this scenario. You should try using playbin2 or decodebin for decoding and it will automatically adjust the queue sizes for playback.

If you have to stick to this pipeline, try setting larger values to the max-size-* properties on the queues.

On a plus side: please move to 1.2 version, 0.10 is obsolete for 2 years now.

Comment: can't move to different version unfortunately because I use some specific plugins written only for 0.10. Thanks for your suggestion about max-size. It helped me.

Comment: Porting from 0.10 to 1.0 isn't hard. If you have the source it should be straightforward to do so. This should help: [porting docs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/docs/random/porting-to-1.0.txt)